# Enter-PSSession works but Invoke-Command does not to install software

Tags: powershell

I have this really weird problem. If I use Powershell to remote to another server with Enter-PsSession and run this command, the software installs:

```
msiexec /i "c:\install\AWS\EC2LaunchV2\AmazonEC2Launch.msi" /qn /lvx C:\install\AWS\EC2Launchv2\AmazonEC2LaunchLog.txt
```

But, if I use Invoke-Command with -ScriptBlock and run the same command, it fails. In both cases, msiexec creates the log file. But, when it fails, it looks like it runs roll-back and ends with a 1603 error.

The only difference between these that I can imagine is the current working directory. I have tried putting in a 'cd' command before the install command to change to a few different directories and none of them worked--"c:\windows\system32, the install file location, my home directory\Documents (which is what shows up when I use Enter-PSSession).

Does anyone have any idea why this is happening? Or at least, any other idea about how I can get Invoke-Command to work? I need to use that because I'm trying to script this.

Comment: check the log file, you should be able to find details about what caused the 1603

Answer (score 0):

Ok, well I still don't know why there is this difference, but I figured out that if I instead run the command as `cmd /c "msiexec ..."`, then it works that way. I'm not sure how to format that for a command that requires quotes within the msiexec command, but fortunately, I can do without them.